# ArrayBlockingQueue NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, blockingqueue

Just for learning, I have written the following code for custom thread pool referring and editing the code shown [here.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html)

As shown in the code I am using ArrayBlockingQueue for task queue.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadPoolService {
    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
    private final int corePoolSize;

    private ThreadPoolService(int corePoolSize) {
        this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
        this.taskQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(corePoolSize);
        ThreadPool[] threadPool = new ThreadPool[corePoolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < corePoolSize; i++) {
            threadPool[i] = new ThreadPool();
            threadPool[i].start();
        }
    }

    public static ThreadPoolService newFixedThreadPool(int size) {
        return new ThreadPoolService(size);
    }

    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        try {
            taskQueue.offer(task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ThreadPool extends Thread {
        Runnable task;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    while (!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        task = taskQueue.remove();
                        task.run();
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolService pool = ThreadPoolService.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Runnable task1 = () -> {
            System.out.println(" Wait for sometime: -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Runnable task2 = () -> System.out.println(" Do  Task 2 -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Runnable task3 = () -> System.out.println(" Do  Task 3 -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Runnable task4 = () -> System.out.println(" Do  Task 4 -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        List<Runnable> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        taskList.add(task1);
        taskList.add(task2);
        taskList.add(task3);
        taskList.add(task4);
        for (Runnable task : taskList) {
            pool.execute(task);
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs fine sometimes and sometimes gives an error.

Success output:

```
Do  Task 2 -> Thread-2
Wait for sometime: -> Thread-8
Do  Task 3 -> Thread-6
Do  Task 4 -> Thread-7
```

Failure output:

```
Do  Task 4 -> Thread-3
Do  Task 3 -> Thread-6
Wait for sometime: -> Thread-4
Do  Task 2 -> Thread-7
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.remove(AbstractQueue.java:117)
    at com.interview.java.ThreadPoolService$ThreadPool.run(ThreadPoolService.java:43)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.remove(AbstractQueue.java:117)
    at com.interview.java.ThreadPoolService$ThreadPool.run(ThreadPoolService.java:43)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.remove(AbstractQueue.java:117)
    at com.interview.java.ThreadPoolService$ThreadPool.run(ThreadPoolService.java:43)
```

I see the reason for the error is the attempt to remove the element when the queue is empty. But it should not because i am doing queue empty check at line no 42 (`while (!taskQueue.isEmpty())`). What is wrong with code and also why it runs without error sometimes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the 'while' check and the actual removal, the queue could be modified by another Thread, possibly resulting in the error you mention. That's called a 'race condition'.

So in order to fix that you'll need a way to block the access to the queue by other threads, either by 'locking', using a 'synchronized' block with a shared lock object. Or simply by 'polling' instead of removing.

Comment: Thanks! replacing taskQueue.remove() by taskQueue.poll() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`BlockingQueue` is thread-safe only on an individual operation level.I'm seeing `check-then-act`operation in the code which is a compound operation which is not thread-safe. To make this code thread-safe perform the `check-then-act` inside a synchronized block and lock on the queue itself.

```
synchronized(taskQueue) {
       while (!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
             task = taskQueue.remove();
             task.run();
 }};
```

**optimization:** If the task is a time consuming one, you can execute it outside the synchronized block. So that other threads don't have to wait till the current task completes.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with code?

You access `taskQueue` field from several threads without synchronization. You must do queue empty check and remove operation atomically, which can be done with `synchronized` keyword:

```
private class ThreadPool extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Runnable task;

        while (true) {
            synchronized(queue) {
                // give access to taskQueue to one thread at a time 
                if (!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    task = taskQueue.remove();
                }
            }

            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> why it runs without error sometimes?

Because of nature of JVM thread scheduler: sometimes it plans thread execution in such a way that they access `taskQueue` synchronously by themselves. But when you deal with multithreading, you can't rely on thread execution order, and must synchronize access to shared objects by yourself.